# Derby database appending space when returning values

Tags: sql, database, derby

Using a Derby Database:

In my addresses table, I have address information, with a column for the zip code of type `varchar(45)`.

If I query `(select * from addresses where address_id = 1234)` and look at the ZIP Column, it returns `'95035'`.

If I query `(select ZIP from addresses where address_id = 1234)` it returns `'95035 '` (With a space at the end).

I noticed this on the zip column because I have a basic validator running on the addresses and it checks for extra spaces in the zip code, so I don't know how widespread this issue is for other columns and tables. Less than .02% of my rows are being affected by this, and if I delete the row and re-enter it with the same data it fixes the problem.

Can anyone tell me why this would be happening/how to fix it?

Comment: When you say `I query ... and look at the ZIP column`, what do you mean? Are you using a SQL IDE like SquirrelSQL or Netbeans? Are you using Derby's `ij` tool? Are you writing a JDBC program yourself? Something else? Can you include a screenshot or program source code?

Comment: Results are consistent when writing and executing queries from RazorSQL, or using a `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` in Java code.

Comment: My best guess is that, in some cases, you are inserting the space when you insert or update the `zip` column in the row, and in other cases you are not. I think it is very unlikely that the value that you get back from the `zip` column depends on whether you `select *` or `select zip`. Are you using the SQL `CAST` operator at all? Perhaps you could include a program that reproduces the problem from scratch with an empty DB?

Comment: I can run the following on one of the rows exhibiting this behavior: `update addresses set zip = '76036' where address_id = 1198388`. No space in what I'm setting the zip column to. Yet when I then run `select zip from addresses where address_id = 1198388` it returns `76036 ` (with a space). I've tried changing the zip to another value and changing it back. The value I change it to initially returns with no space after the zip, but when I change it back it then has the space again.

Comment: The things I have gotten to work successfully are changing the value to a completely different value (using 9-digit instead of 5 digit zip code) and dropping the row and re-adding the same values. 

I am not using SQL `CAST` at all. I have presented the exact queries I am using.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be more help. I've used Derby for nearly 15 years and never heard of anything like this. If you can present an actual program that reproduces this that would really help. Seems like you can reproduce something on your system, so hopefully you can narrow it down and post some actual code.